# duplicate http requests javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to duplicate all requests made on a webpage? In example I need to have form data on 2 different servers, but I cannot change the backend on the server which generates the response. So I cannot forward the data to the second server.

This has to be done for a lot of different pages.

I need a dynamic solution which duplicates all requests made by the client so I don't need to change every webpage, but can just add one script to the pages.

Comment: one potential issue you'll have with two different servers is CORS - which means you'd have to change the backend anyway

Comment: CORS could be fixed, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: you'll likely need to change every request to use a new function - monkey patching XMLHttpRequest may work, or if you're using jQuery there's probably some hook or other you can use - really, without a clue of any code, all you'll get is vague possibilities

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have configured CORS. You can do a javascript function that repeat the request for each server. For example:

```
function MultiXHR() {

    this.servers = ["http://server1.com", "http://server2.com"];
    this.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    this.request = function(type, uri, data, onready){
        for (var server in this.servers){
            var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            url = this.servers[server] + "/" + uri;
            console.log(url);
            httpRequest.open(type,url, true);
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = onready;
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", this.contentType);
            httpRequest.send(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this object like this:

```
m = new MultiXHR();
m.request('POST',"example","data=data");
```